# Setting the correct date on notes imported to iCloud

Tags: macos, datetime, import, applescript, icloud

I'm using the following script (which I found online) to import old notes into iCloud, via the Notes OS X app. The import works fine, but all the imported notes show as created at time of import.

I wrote in a section of code that should copy the date from the original note file and set the new note's date to that, but for some reason it isn't working. The date is being copied correctly, and as far as I can tell, the second part executes as well, since there isn't any error, but the date always ends up being the import date.

If anyone can spot the issue or has any ideas, I would very much appreciate it!

```
-- choose the folder with the notes
set notesFolder to choose folder

-- find all the files in that folder
tell application "Finder"
    set noteFiles to (files of entire contents of notesFolder) as alias list
end tell

-- get the name of the account that you want to add the notes to
set accountName to getNameOfTargetAccount()

-- get the name of the folder to add the notes to
set folderName to getNameOfTargetFolderOfAccount(accountName)

-- make sure the folder exists in Notes
tell application "Notes"
    tell account accountName
        if not (exists folder folderName) then make new folder with properties {name:folderName}
    end tell
end tell

repeat with noteFile in noteFiles
    -- get the note name from the file name and the corresponding dates
    set {noteName, ext} to getName_andExtension(noteFile)

    tell application "Finder"
        set noteModified to modification date of noteFile
        set noteCreated to creation date of noteFile

    end tell

    -- get the file's text as html
    if ext is "html" then
        set noteText to read noteFile
    else
        -- convert the file's contents into html code
        set noteText to do shell script "/usr/bin/textutil -stdout -convert html " & quoted form of POSIX path of noteFile & " | /usr/bin/tidy -ib -utf8"
    end if

    -- add the note to the folder
    tell application "Notes"
        tell account accountName
            tell folder folderName
                make new note with properties {name:noteName, body:noteText, modification date:noteModified, creation date:noteCreated}
            end tell
        end tell
    end tell
end repeat


(****************** SUBROUTINES *****************)
-- this lets you choose which acount you want to target
-- if there's only 1 account then that account name is returned
on getNameOfTargetAccount()
    tell application "Notes"
        if (count of accounts) is greater than 1 then
            set theseAccountNames to the name of every account
            set thisAccountName to choose from list theseAccountNames with prompt "Add note to which account?"
            if thisAccountName is false then error number -128
            set thisAccountName to thisAccountName as text
        else
            set thisAccountName to the name of first account
        end if
        return thisAccountName
    end tell
end getNameOfTargetAccount

-- this lets you choose which folder you want to target from an account
-- if there's only 1 folder then that folder name is returned
on getNameOfTargetFolderOfAccount(accountName)
    set folderName to missing value
    tell application "Notes"
        tell account accountName
            if (count of folders) is greater than 1 then
                set theseFolderNames to the name of every folder
                set folderName to choose from list theseFolderNames with prompt "Add note to which folder?"
                if folderName is false then error number -128
                set folderName to folderName as text
            else
                set folderName to the name of first folder
            end if
        end tell
    end tell
    return folderName
end getNameOfTargetFolderOfAccount

on getName_andExtension(f)
    set f to f as text
    set {name:nm, name extension:ex} to info for file f without size
    if ex is missing value then
        set ex to ""
    else
        set nm to text 1 thru ((count nm) - (count ex) - 1) of nm
    end if
    return {nm, ex}
end getName_andExtension
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `Notes.app`'s scripting dictionary it states that those are read-only (`r/o`):

```
creation date (date, r/o) : the creation date of the note
modification date (date, r/o) : the modification date of the note
```

Comment: BTW: the notes are stored in a sqlite database ( ~/Library/Containers/com.apple.Notes/Data/Library/Notes/NotesV3.storedata )

Comment: Thanks for the info. I was hoping that since I was trying to set them up during note creation, it would get through. I ended up installing 10.7 Lion on a partition of an external drive and used an iTunes/Mail combo to import the notes with dates intact.